# Do I need Devise and CommunityEngine on the same app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, communityengine

I'm building a new social site in Rails(4), and want to use some of the social networking features available in CommunityEngine. Do I also need to add Devise for signups, or does CommunityEngine now have that capability too?

At this time I'm not offering Omniauth configuration through Fb or Twitter, g+ and so on.

I'm open to any additional recommendations you might have as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i will suggest you to use `devise` for signin/signout/password management etc and `community engine` to handle the applications community functions such as blog,posts,profile management,user upload and comments..lets keep authentication seperate because [community](http://communityengine.org/) gem is made for enabling social functions not authentication which is a secoondry function or add-on ..so you can go ahead and use devise for authentication and community gem seperately hence *keeping both modules seperate* and they both work hand in hand without any probs